# Backend в Create React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Начинал изучать React, собрал проект с помощью Create React App, и теперь хочу начать делать серверную часть на Node.js. Но не имею даже представления о том, как и где это делается. Видимо, я не понимаю чего-то фундаментального. Судя по тому, что мне удалось узнать по этой теме, Create React App в принципе не создавался с учетом на то, что с помощью него будут делать и фронтэнд на реакте, и серверную часть для работы с базой данных или рендеринга мета-тегов на стороне сервера. Помогите с этим разобраться, а то у меня не получается никак сложить два и два. В моем понимании мне все еще сложно понять, где заканчивается фронтэнд, а где начинается бэкэнд, когда и то и другое пишется на JS, словно я никак не могу осознать нечто очевидное и само собой разумеющееся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добро пожаловаться на SO!

React - это фронтэнд, то, что видит пользователь.

Для бэкэнда (всего, что будет скрыто от доступа пользователя) нужно использовать свои фрэймворки. На бэкэнд будут поступать запросы из браузера от пользователя (React'a), он будет их обрабатывать, связываться с БД, отправлять статические файлы и т.д.

Я рекомендую next.js, наиболее же старым и распространённым является [expressjs.](https://expressjs.com/)

Бэкэнд запускается с помощью [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Также для работы серверной части рекомендую присмотреться к PM2, который будет отвечать за запуск сервера на node.js, его перезагрузку если вдруг что-то сломалось и масштабирование.

И бэкэнд и фронтэнд пишутся на JS, но если вы только начинаете изучать всё это дело, то рекомендую для всего использовать typescript.

Comment: Спасибо! С express, fastify и прочем подобном вроде понял. Но пока гуглил наткнулся еще на Next,js, и не совсем понял к чему его отнести. Я так понял это фреймворк более широкого профиля и для фронтэнда и для сервера? Или это решение для тех, кто решил удариться в изоморфные приложения? Кстати об этом, в связке с тем же express получится ведь использовать изоморфные возможности react?

Comment: @ВалерийПальянов next.js - это фрэймворк для рэндеринга реакта на сервере (что хорошо для SEO) и его также можно использовать вместе с указанными мной backend'ами. Достаточно звезд на github, много контрибьюторов, хорошая документация, так что вполне можно попробовать его. К тому же его не нужно настраивать, работает, как говорится, из коробки :)

Comment: А как же пыха (PHP)? На котором крутится 90% всех бизнес-приложений...

Comment: @СергейВ. Пыха - это уже прошлое :)